# How to install OTF fonts with otfinst.py?

Tags: fonts

I want to install some fonts that I have in OTF format for use in LaTeX.

I learned that I should use `otfinst.py`, but I have absolutely no idea how. The manual is by far the worst ever I've seen.

I have three files, that I'd like to convert: Crimson-Roman.otf, Crimson-Bold.otf, Crimson-Italic.otf, and Crimson-BoldItalic.otf.

The script asks for a "berryname" which I have no Idea where to set it, or what it should be.
I want to use the old-style numerics in that font, how do I generate them, and how do I select them in LaTeX?

And what about all the other textual replacements in the OTF file, do those glyphs get converted, too?

And what's the deal with the font encoding? It uses Ly1, what is that? I need UTF-8 if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: You could try [autoinst](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/utilities/fontools/). Old-stylye numbers should work out of the box in LaTeX with autoinst.

Comment: Here's a good TUGboat article covering this topic: The installation and use of OpenType fonts in LaTeX https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-2/tb87owens.pdf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a good news for you: if  you use XeTeX or LuaTeX, you don't have to convert OTF fonts, you can just use them directly by installing them in your system.

Here is an example on Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo cp EBGaramond.otf /usr/local/share/fonts
$ sudo fc-cache /usr/local/share/fonts
$ fc-list | grep Garamond
EB Garamond:style=Regular
```

and then you can use it in LaTeX:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
```

All OpenType features are available via `fontspec`. See for example [this project](https://github.com/raphink/geneve_1564/blob/master/geneve_1564.tex) which makes an heavy use of OpenType features with XeTeX.

So unless you heavily rely on specific PDFTex functionalities, I would really recommend you use XeTeX (or LuaTeX) if you want to use OTF fonts.

Comment: I'll take a look at it, I've installed xetex, and see if I can can switch from pdflatex. Is it possible to have local font directories? like ~./fonts (this is where I keep my locally installed fonts) or something?

Comment: Using `~.fonts` should be possible with `fontconfig` (`fc-list`, `fc-cache` and friends). `fontspec` also lets you use local files if you prefer, by giving the name of the font file instead of the name returned by `fc-list`.

Comment: As a note, when switching to XeTeX, you have to get rid of the encoding lines such as `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` since XeTeX supports UTF-8 natively. Also get rid of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` if you use it.

Comment: Great, I'll check later today, and accept your answer when I'm happy with what I got.

Comment: Please don't accept this answer without changing the question. It does not answer the question you asked.

Comment: @frabjous: that's right, it doesn't answer the question, it only suggests that the problem might not really exist, so it addresses the issue instead of the specific question. I have supposed that the goal was to use OpenType fonts and features, the easiest way as possible, and that the user was not aware that conversion was not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 16):

I have successfully converted Adobe Garamond Pro some time ago. Proceed at own risk.

Start with creating a directory where you put the OTF files and the script `otfinst.py`. You need to configure the script to fit your requirements.

**1. Set the encoding**

For T1, the relevant part of the script should be edited as the following:

```
encoding = 'T1'
encodings = { 'T1':
              { 'berryencoding': '8t',
                'commandline': '-e fontools_t1',
                },
              }
```

**2. Set where to put the fonts**

Using `kpsewhich`, the script finds your `TEXMFHOME` directory automatically, but it needs to be told the location for fonts. I am not sure about other operating systems, but using MacTeX with Mac OS X, there are three possible directories:

- `/usr/local/texlive/2011` – requires root access; should not be modified by a user;
- `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` – requires root access;
- `~/Library/texmf` – this is the `TEXMFHOME` that `kpsewhich` finds, so you need to specify the route from here.

The route in the script is already set correctly: `localfontsdir = '/tex/latex/localfonts/'`

**3. Which OpenType options to support**

As the script clearly explains, it picks one choice from each element and takes all permutations. Kerning and ligatures are always selected and one of the additional choices is support for old numerals (`onum`), so it should satisfy your needs.

**4. Set the Berry name**

*The Berry names are used by LaTeX to identify the font family and corresponding fonts. There is also Berry encoding for options, such as lining numerals, old numerals, bold, semibold, etc. I am not an expert, but I think that by combining these two, LaTeX chooses the appropriate files (as I can do the same manually).*

If your font family is not included in [this document](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/fontname/adobe.map), you should run `otfinfo --family` to get its name and then make a custom Berry name. Therefore:

```
$otfinfo --family Crimson-Roman.otf
```

Suppose the output was `Crimson`. Think of an original 3-letter designation (not to interfere with existing fonts), e.g. `c12` and edit the script accordingly:

```
berryname = { 'Minion Pro' : 'pmn',
                                            <missing part>
          'Hypatia Sans Pro' : 'phy',
          'Crimson' : 'c12',
          }
```

**5. Save and run**

Save and run the script. In Mac OS X, `cd` to the directory containing the fonts and the script and run:

```
$sudo python otfinst.py Crimson*
```

Enter the root/superuser password (because of `texhash` at the end) and you should see the activity. After the script ends, it runs the mentioned `texhash`, but I had to run it again myself later as I did not have `nfssext-cfr.sty`. Anyway, you should now explore the configured `localfonts` directory inside `TEXMFHOME` and there should be a file called `crimson.sty`. Open it to see the available commands e.g. to set old numerals. You may need to [download](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nfssext-cfr) the `nfssext-cfr.sty` in case you do not already have it (put it in the same directory and run `$sudo texhash` again).

**6. Test**

Create a test file with `\usepackage{crimson}` in the preamble and compile using pdfTeX. It should be working properly.

Comment: To clarify my intentions when writing this answer, I agree that if there is a possibility to use XeTeX/LuaTeX, it is better to do so rather than converting fonts, but since I have not found any clear explanation of the process, I decided to create a guide just after I succeeded. However, as it is not _rocket science_, putting it on CTAN is probably excessive, so tex.sx seemed to be ideal and this question was a perfect opportunity. I do not encourage the OP to prefer conversion to XeTeX/LuaTeX.

Comment: absolutely, your how-to is much appreciated