# Reduce compilation time for opentype fonts (otf)

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, profiling

I have some opentype fonts (`otf`) which I use with `fontspec`. Everything works fine.

During the compilation LuaLaTeX load the `otf`-files in a temporary file.

For example:

```
(load: /home/marco/.texlive2011/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/temp-FONTNAME.lua)
```

Is it possible to install the font via LuaLaTeX or `fontspec` that the compilation will be reduced?

I know the script [otfins.py](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24691/how-to-install-otf-fonts-with-otfinst-py) but maybe there is an easier way.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The temp-FONTNAME-file will be created the first time you use the font and then normally lualatex should reuse it if you don't delete it between compilations. (The file contains informations similar to the one in a tfm. You can open it in a text editor to inspect it.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for the reply. I have the  feeling that without installing the otf-file as normal the compilation time is very high. In my example I tested minion pro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: no you can't. Long answer: *fontspec* uses *luaotfload* to load fonts. And *luaotfload* (which is based on ConTeXt's fontloader) needs a lot of information when you are in `node`-mode. This information is stored in big Lua tables that get loaded (created) when processing the document. And processing these tables take time.

That said: it is possible to create your own font loader in LuaTeX which speeds up things. When you restrict yourself to the TeX way of handling fonts (no contextual ligatures AFAIK, no language dependent font usage), the required table is **much** smaller and therefore when using a cache, loading a font should only take a fraction of the time it takes with *luaotfload*.

Comment: I think context contains code to improve speed. The font caches of contexte.g. seems to be stored in binary files (.tmc).

Comment: @Patrick: Please have a look at my other question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34153/usage-of-luatexsuppressfontnotfounderror