# EB Garamond on LaTeX

Tags: fonts, ebgaramond

I'm looking for the EB Garamond font on LaTeX. Precisely that. And my search, on Google and on TeX.SX, hasn't returned anything, yet.

I'm aware that I can have URW-Garamond No. 8 on LaTeX, e.g., `\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}`, and I know I can have EB Garamond on XeTeX, but these are not what I'm looking for.

Comment: There is a link on the first link on Google where you can download it. But without XeLatTeX how do you plan to use it?

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24691/how-to-install-otf-fonts-with-otfinst-py

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In the meantime, an [`ebgaramond`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ebgaramond) package has arrived on CTAN. It also features Type 1 fonts, and thus can be used with pdflatex, too. Use it via

```
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
```

Package options for old style/lining figures, and proportional/tabular figures are `osf`, `lf`, `p`, and `t`, among others. There is even a `microtype` configuration for this font.

Answer (score 12):

The font EB Garamond, by Georg Duffner, may be obtained (among other sites) from the [author's own website](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/).

It's an OpenType font; after installing it, you'll need to use either [Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX to load it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37251/5001). Or, follow the link in the comment provided by Marco Daniel and use [Harrold Cavendish's method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24699/5001) to make it usable under pdf(La)TeX.

Comment: `EB Garamond` is now accesible from  `texlive` and a doc having  the `\usepackage{ebgaramond}` line in the preamble compiles with  `pdflatex`.

Comment: @MátéWierdl - Thanks. The availability of the `ebgaramond` package is also mentioned in the [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102719/5001) to the query at hand. The latter answer was posted about nine months *after* I posted mine (back in June 2012). Put differently, the `ebgaramond` package appears to have come on the scene sometime between June 2012 and March 2013.

Comment: I just noticed that the  `mathdesign` package doesn't throw an error for the  `ebgaramond` (or any other) option,  and it gives some kind of default math alphabet which is not "garamond"-like which would be a slender and forward leaning math font.  Luckily we can  have `\usepackage{ebgaramond}{newtxmath}` for a well fitting math font for `ebgaramond`.