# Problem with conversion from OpenType to Type 1 fonts using otfinst

Tags: fonts, opentype

I would like to use a family of OpenType fonts with pdfLaTeX (more precisely, Utopia Std from Adobe). I have tried using the Python script `otfinst` following the clear guideline provided by Harrold Cavendish in [How to install OTF fonts with otfinst.py?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24691/how-to-install-otf-fonts-with-otfinst-py). I have followed all the steps, but when I run the script, I get the error message `Index Error: list index out of range`, and no file generation.

I am using MikTeX 2.9 on Windows XP, and the script is in the same folder as the .otf files to be processed. Anyone could possibly help on this issue? I have checked online that this has been happening to some people, but nobody seemed to provide an answer.

Comment: I had a similar problem on Mac OS X and [asked on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1986423/44082).

Comment: Does it have to be `otfinst`? I gave a short desription of `otftotfm` in my answer to [How do I use TrueType Fonts with PDFTeX using otftotfm?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52819/how-do-i-use-truetype-fonts-with-pdftex-using-otftotfm). The question was focused on TTF, but of course, `otftotfm` works with OTF as well...

Comment: I tried the `otfinst` with a new python and couldn't get it to work at all. I get syntax errors and "inconsistent tab and space" errors.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: I had exactly the same problem trying with Python 2.7. Then that problem seemed to disappear and got that one depicted in my post. Btw, this is related to my post about the `fourier` package with the `expert` option. I thought of getting the Type 1 encoding from the .otf files as I had done for MinionPro, but in that case a collection of base files where provided that now I have to obtain directly from the .otf.

Comment: @Marcos: `otfinst.py` mixes tabs and spaces for indentation sometimes even in one line. Also the print commands uses the wrong syntax for python3. Also it assumes e.g. that `TEXMFHOME` is set (which isn't true on miktex) and probably does other assumtions too. Beside this: if your fourier `pfb` has the ligature, the simplest would be to write an .enc-file. But one needs the `afm` to find the glyph names.