# How to install Type 1 font in MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: fonts, installing, miktex, type1

What is the procedure to install Type 1 font in MiKTeX 2.9?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Do you compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? See for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24691/how-to-install-otf-fonts-with-otfinst-py

Comment: but i am using latex not xelatex.

Comment: Does this work for you? I didn't try it.
[Adding a PostScript font in MiKTeX](http://www.macrotex.net/addfont.html)

Comment: @Katrijn The page is outdated. E.g.  today you shouldn't change config.ps.

Comment: Your question is to vage. Possible answers can be anything from "use fontinst" to "use the package manager of miktex".

Answer (score 5):

LaTeX can't use Type1 fonts directly. It needs to have metric informations in files `.tfm`.

There are Type 1 fonts already prepared for using with LaTeX. For example you can use the font `libertine` with including `\usepackage{libertine}` in your document. The package `libertine-legacy` on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertine-legacy/) contains all you need.

If your font (can you give us the name?) is not yet prepared for using with LaTeX you have to do this by your own. The perl script `ìnstallfont` by Josef Kleber also may be helpful (search [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/installfont)).

To learn more how to install fonts the [font installation guide](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/info/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide/fontinstallationguide.pdf) might be again helpful too.

Comment: And in the year 2012 modern TeX engines (i.e. XeTeX and LuaTeX) can use _OpenType_ fonts _without_ any installation magic. So: **Use OpenType fonts with XeTeX/LuaTeX**.