# Mathtype Euclid Font in Latex

Tags: fonts

Is there anyway that I can use `Mathtype's Euclid` font in typing *texts* in LaTeX? Just for the text, not the math mode. Some used to suggest that it's the same as the default `Computer Modern` font in LaTeX, but I strongly disagree with that, and I'm still desperate to use this font in LaTeX. If that's possible, what should I do?

Comment: How do you compile your document? `pdflatex` or `xelatex`/`lualatex`. If you use the last ones you can simple add True Type fonts: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24691/how-to-install-otf-fonts-with-otfinst-py

Comment: I'm using pdflatex. It seems like I can't avoid using xelatex or lualatex as you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel A ahort answer?

Comment: I'm surprised that you think the Euclid font is so different from Computer Modern. They seem very similar, to me. What are the big differences, in you view?

Answer (score 2):

With LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, any system font may be used. I don't have Euclid installed, so I've used a generic replacement. You can replace `Times New Roman` with the name of any system-installed font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % allows loading of system fonts
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} % replace with your desired font

\begin{document}
Hello world! And math ($a^2 + b^2 = c^2$) is still in Computer Modern:
\[ \sin^2 u + \cos^2 u = 1 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]