# FontAwesome font not found?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontawesome

I'm using the latest version of MacTeX 2013 on OS X 10.8.4. All of my TeX Live packages are fully up-to-date. TeX Live also lists the `fontawesome` package as installed.

I'm trying to use the FontAwesome font with `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX` and getting font-not-found errors. The exact message is:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexmf FontAwesome
! I can't find file `FontAwesome'.
```

There's a longer traceback which I am omitting for brevity. Let me know if it's needed to resolve this problem.

I have already tried running the following commands, to no avail:

```
sudo -H mktexlsr
sudo -H updmap-sys
```

Other than the above two commands, this is a 100% new out-of-the-box installation, with no modifications whatsoever.

Here's a minimal broken example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\faTwitter
\end{document}
```

How can I add this missing font?

*Edit* (Q1 2021): Please see Justin Curry's answer regarding an update to the package name from `fontawesome` to `fontawesome5`.

Comment: FontAwesome can be found at CTAN [at this location](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome). I am not sure how you can add this to your OS X 10.8.4, I do not use this OS or MacText. But did you take a look at [this one](http://tug.org/mactex/fonts/)?

Comment: FontAwesome provides an OTF font, which apparently is not being copied to the correct font directory. This [post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24691/how-to-install-otf-fonts-with-otfinst-py) suggests how you might proceed

Comment: @Llaves - It's probably not so much an issue of the font file not being copied to the correct directory but of the font not having been "activated" correctly. Just copying a font file to the user's `~/Library/Fonts` directory doesn't activate it, at least not in a way suitable for use under MacOSX. Under MacOSX, the easiest way I know to "activate" a font is to load it in the `FontBook` application and click on the "Install Font" button. Doing so also copies the font file to `~/Library/Fonts`...

Comment: @Mico Luaotfload doesn’t care for a font’s “activation state” (whatever that is). As long as it is in a system path the font will be indexed. I suggest that OP remove the package and copy the otf files into the system font path manually. Then run ``luaotfload-tool --update`` and retry.

Comment: @phg -- I may not have expressed myself sufficiently clearly. As I noted in the "full" answer, LuaLaTeX was able to compile the MWE even before the otf version of the font was downloaded and "officially activated". It was XeLaTeX that couldn't compile the MWE before the font was properly activated.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

On my MacBook (running MacTeX 2013 under MacOSX 10.7.5), your example compiles correctly under `LuaLaTeX` if I add the instruction `\usepackage{fontspec}`:

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faTwitter
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: After I downloaded the OpenType version of this font -- BTW, the version at https://fontawesome.com/docs seems to be slightly newer than the one on the CTAN -- and "activated" it by opening it in the `FontBook` application and clicking on the "Install" button, the MWE above also compiles correctly under XeLaTeX. This is not exactly surprising, I suppose, as `Xe(La)TeX` depends heavily on the underlying operating system for activities such as loading fonts.

---

*Addendum*, mid-February 2020: The demo document shown above continues to work correctly under LuaLaTeX when run under TeXLive2019 or MacTeX2019. To get it to compile under XeLaTeX, you will probably need to insert the instruction

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Path = /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/}
```

between the instructions `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\usepackage{fontawesome}`.

The file `FontAwesome.otf` that's distributed with MacTeX2019 has version number 4.6.3. There is a slightly newer version of the OpenType font file -- version 4.7.0, to be precise -- on [github](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/v4.7.0/fonts/FontAwesome.otf). Both 4.6.3 and 4.7.0 date back to 2016. A minor caveat: I haven't actually tested out the slightly newer version of `FontAwesome.otf`. However, I believe it should be compatible with the `fontawesome` package.

Comment: `\usepackage{fontspec}` did the trick. I'm actually using the `moderncv` package, which recently added support for FontAwesome icons. I'll contact the author and suggest he add the `fontspec` package to his template.

Comment: "Opening in the FontBook application". For recent versions of Mac OS: "File" > "Validate File ..." > Select the OTF file and after validating check box to install font. Get the OTF file from GitHub here: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts

Comment: @Mico your answer gives hints on how to activate a font using FontBook. This part of the answer is out of date as FontBook changed the wording for the menus in their application.

Comment: @Unapiedra - Thanks. I don't think it's right to say that the method I described, back in Sept. 2013, is "out of date". For sure, it is still possible to drag-and-drop font files from the Finder onto the FontBook icon and then to click on the "Install" button that pops up in a dialogue box. By the way, your alternative method deserves a separate answer, not just a comment below mine. Please consider posting a new answer; that way, it'll be seen by many more people.

Comment: Hi, can you update your answer with  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472090/166923 ?

Comment: @ColonD - Ok. Am away from my Mac laptop all day -- will update this answer tonight.

Comment: The link should now be https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/v4.7.0/fonts/FontAwesome.otf since Font Awesome 5 isn’t compatible with `fontawesome` package.

Comment: @FranklinYu - Thanks for this. I've noticed that the link you provide points to version 4.7.0 (year: 2016) of the font file. In contrast, what's distributed with TeXLive2019 and MacTeX2019 is version 4.6.3 (also 2016). Would you happen to know if there's a major difference between these versions? Please advise.

Comment: I didn’t notice that it dates back to 2016! They seems to have stopped maintenance on that branch. Maybe the MacTex one is easier then.

Comment: I found `\defaultfontfeatures{Path = ...}` nukes finding default fonts. I needed to use `\defaultfontfeatures[FontAwesome]{Path = /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/}` to ensure I didn't change the path for every font lookup.

Comment: why the latex did not scan path  /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist automatically?

Comment: @Dolphin - A "why"-type question back to you: it's currently late-July 2023 -- *Why* are you still running TeXLive2019? Put differently: Is there something that's preventing you from employing an up-to-date TeX distribution?

Comment: I am using the 2023, the path could not edit when I found the version is legacy.

Comment: @Dolphin - ah, so you *are* using TeXlive2023. Thanks for clarifying. Why, then, should the program *ever* search `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist`. It's far better off searching `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist`, no? Conversely, if you really don't want to use TeXlive2023, why are you running its programs? I guess I'm mostly showing that I have no clear idea as to (a) what you're doing and (b) what you want to be doing. Sorry.

Answer (score 31):

On Ubuntu, you can install **fontawesome** using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

Comment: The other answers confused me. What is really *missing* is the system font, which can be installed like this.

Comment: -1GB after installation :(

Comment: `apt-get install fonts-font-awesome` was enough for me, and it's only 1.4MB.

Answer (score 25):

If anyone wants to get this working with `xelatex` without installing the font into your system, see section *4.2 By file name* of the [fontspec.pdf](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex2e/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) manual:

> [Loading the font by file name] is also necessary in XeTeX when loading OpenType fonts that are present within your TEX distribution, such as `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public`. Fonts in such locations are visible to XeTeX but cannot be loaded by font name, only file name; LuaTEX does not have this restriction.

Since `fontawesome.sty` simply references the font by name:

```
% definition of \FA as a shortcut to load the Font Awesome font
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
```

We have to set the default `Path` to locate the font, before loading `fontawesome`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{
    Path = /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/ }
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\faTwitter
\end{document}
```

You may have to change `Path` depending on where `fontawesome` is installed. Assuming you're using TeX Live, you can find the relative path to the font file by running:

```
tlmgr info --list fontawesome
```

Output:

```
package:     fontawesome
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Font containing web-related icons.
longdesc:    The package offers access to the large number of web-related icons provided by the included font. The package requires the package, fontspec, running under XeTeX or LuaTeX.
installed:   Yes
revision:    31020
sizes:       doc: 173k, run: 101k
relocatable: Yes
cat-version: 3.1.1
cat-date:    2014-04-26 20:05:48 +0200
cat-license: other-free
collection:  collection-fontsextra
Included files, by type:
run files:
  texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.otf
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty
doc files:
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontawesome/README details="Readme"
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.pdf
  texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.tex
```

Answer (score 22):

You just need to install (by double clicking) the `FontAwesome.otf` that comes with MacTeX on the macOs system fonts. (The new fonts downloaded from github didn't work for me.)

My `FontAwesome.otf` is in:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome
```

You can locate your file with:

```
tlmgr info --list fontawesome
```

Comment: you need to be higher, this is the best method to get the correct version of the font

Comment: This is the only answer that helped me to get [Developer CV](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/developer-cv) working. Thanks!

Comment: This answer did it for me. I used `lualatex` and ran it twice. First time it compiled the font, then the second time it picked itup. However, I imagine I could add more search paths to the `${TEXMFSYSVAR}/fonts/conf/fonts.conf`.

Comment: GitHub still works, but you need a different link because the developers decide to make breaking change in Font Awesome 5. Font Awesome 4 is still available on GitHub via https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/v4.7.0/fonts/FontAwesome.otf.

Answer (score 12):

**Ultimately, you need `/path/to/FontAwesome.otf` to be produced by `\newfontfamily\FA[Path=/path/to/,Extension=.otf]{FontAwesome}`.**

*Note this answer assumes you didn't add the TeX Live fonts to the system environment variables such that they are found when fontspec searches the system fonts. (either because you don't know how or because it isn't practical e.g. multi-client Version Control System situation where you can't guarantee that every client has the same system environment variables).*

Assuming you are using XeLaTeX: To minimize maintenance with each sequential TeX Live release (2015,2016, etc.), I chose to add `\defaultfontfeatures{Extension = .otf}` rather than provide an explicit path.

This is because XeLaTeX automatically loads `$(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFSYSVAR)/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf` into its path.

## texlive-fontconfig.conf from TeX Live 2015

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

With each release, this gets updated, so you don't have any maintenance costs ;)

So you only need to add the extension parameter to `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}` indirectly this way. This is of course provided that the fonts you're using are OTF.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Extension = .otf}% adds .otf to end of path when font loaded without ext parameter e.g. \newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome} > \newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome.otf}
\usepackage{fontawesome} % Relevant path loaded (TeX Live 2015 expansion): /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/FontAwesome causing missing font

\begin{document}
\faTwitter This is a test.
\end{document}
```

---

As a fun exercise to prove your understanding, you could create a document like this:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%\defaultfontfeatures{
%  Extension = .otf
%}
%\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newfontfamily\fatest{FontAwesome.otf} % Explicitly provide .otf
%or
%\newfontfamily\fatest[Extension=.otf]{FontAwesome}


\begin{document}
%\faTwitter This is a test
{\fatest\char"F099} This is a test
\end{document}
```

This works because the following are equivalent:

- `\newfontfamily\fatest{FontAwesome.otf}`
- `\newfontfamily\fatest[Extension=.otf]{FontAwesome}`
- `\defaultfontfeatures{Extension = .otf}\newfontfamily{\fatest}{FontAwesome}`

because they all yield a platform-independent paths.

e.g. Unix-based:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/FontAwesome.otf
```

and `fontspec` will try to load a font by adding each prefix listed in this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
ANYTHING IN HERE GETS PREFIXED to the font file
</fontconfig>
```

See [tex.stackexchange.com/a/313886/13552](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313886/13552)

Comment: with your command `\newfontfamily\fatest{FontAwesome.otf}`, how can I join it with `FA[Path=\@fontdir]`... where I have an example which originally used `\newfontfamily\FA[Path=\@fontdir]{FontAwesome}`

Comment: @lukeg I am not sure what you mean by "join it", but I assume you mean "make it compatible with". Without knowing what your `\@fontdir` contains, I would venture to guess that you just need to add `,Extension = .otf` as a parameter to `\newfontfamily\FA`. **Do not forget to add a trailing slash to the path!** If your `\@fontdir` contains a path other than the built-in TeX Live FontAwesome.otf path, then you'd need to put a copy of FontAwesome.otf at that path. Ultimately, you need `/path/to/FontAwesome.otf` to be produced by `\newfontfamily\FA[Path=\@fontdir,Extension=.otf]{FontAwesome}`.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue recently (Jan 2021) and after installing Font Awesome 5's fonts via Font Book and doing everything I thought was necessary, there turned out to be a one character (!) solution.

Replace

```
\usepackage{fontawesome}
```

with

```
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
```

That's it. I was led to this after seeing Franklin Yu's comment above to the accepted answer, which remarks that Font Awesome 5 is not compatible with the `fontawesome` package. Why they didn't just update the `fontawesome` and had to create a whole new `fontawesome5` package is beyond me.

https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5?lang=en

Comment: Just updated my answer to include this!

Answer (score 4):

I guess it might be caused by missing a step of post-installation of TeX Live. From the [instruction](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-340003.4.4) provided tug.org, it would be like this below.

1. Make sure you have imported TeX Live binaries to your `PATH`. If not, you may refer this [section](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-310003.4.1).
2. Check the value of `TEXMFSYSVAR`.

   ```
   $ kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFSYSVAR
   ```
3. Copy `TEXMFSYSVAR/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf` to your font config directory (e.g. to `/etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf`). Or if you have not enough privileges to do, you may copy to your `HOME` direcotory as well, e.g.

   ```
   $ cp `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFSYSVAR`/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf \
     ~/.fonts.conf
   ```
4. Run `fc-cache` to refresh fontconfig

   ```
   $ fc-cache -fv
   ```

   If you copy the conf file to a system-wide directory, e.g. `/etc/fonts/conf.d` as mentioned before, probably you need to run

   ```
   $ sudo fc-cache -fsv
   ```

   or

   ```
   # fc-cache -fsv
   ```
5. Eventually, check `fc-list` to make sure you've installed `fontawesome`

   ```
   $ fc-list | grep 'fontawesome'
   ```

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 19.04:

```
sudo apt install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

Then use fontawesome5:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fontawesome5}

 \begin{document}
 \faTwitter
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The fontawesome package when using XeLaTeX assumes that the file `FontAwesome.otf` exists in the right place, but recent versions of FontAwesome, will install `Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400.otf` and `Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf`.

I thought about playing with `defaultfontFeatures[FontAwesome]` after `\usepackage{fontspec}` and before `\usepackage{fontawesome}`, but a much simpler approach was to find an version of `FontAwesome.oft` and simply install that on my Mac.

Comment: This is a useful answer for anyone who did install the current Font Awesome desktop files. Just to add to it, the last Font Awesome 4 release ([4.7.0](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/)) provides a `FontAwesome.otf`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some excellent answers already. Below are some steps that worked for me on `macOS BigSur` in March 2021 with `TexLive 2020`, with the intent of compiling with `pdfLatex`. It follows closely this 2016 step-by-step guide: https://theoryl1.wordpress.com/2016/01/15/fontawesome-in-pdftex/ and I am posting here for reference for my future self and hopefully others:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{fontawesome}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{listings}% verbatim with breaklines option
    \lstset{%
      language=[LaTeX]TeX,
      basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    }


    \begin{document}
    Font Awesome is a font that provides scalable icons that can easily be used in text. To install fontawesome, follow these steps:

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    Download the zip file with \verb|wget| or any other method:

    \qquad \verb|wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/fontawesome.zip|

    If you do not have \verb|wget| installed, you may install it via \verb|homebrew| or \verb|macports| or some other method. Example:

    \begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]
       ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
    \end{lstlisting}

    \qquad \verb|brew install wget|

    \item
    Unzip the zip file and save its contents in \verb|~/texmf/|:

    \qquad \verb|unzip fontawesome.zip|

    \qquad \verb|mkdir -p ~/texmf/|

    \qquad \verb|mkdir -p ~/texmf/doc/fonts/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|mkdir -p ~/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|mkdir -p ~/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|mkdir -p ~/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|mkdir -p ~/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|mkdir -p ~/texmf/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|cd fontawesome|

    \qquad \verb|mv README.md ~/texmf/doc/fonts/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|mv doc/* ~/texmf/doc/fonts/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|mv enc/* ~/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|mv map/* ~/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|mv opentype/* ~/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|mv tfm/* ~/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|mv type1/* ~/texmf/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|mv tex/* ~/texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome/|

    \qquad \verb|cd ..|

    \qquad \verb|rm -rf fontawesome|

    \item 
    Update the font map:

    \qquad \verb|updmap -sys|

    \item 
    Check that the map file has been registered.

    \qquad \verb|kpsewhich fontawesome.map|

    \item
    Run \verb|pdfLaTeX| on this minimal example. The output below should look like an automobile and a bicycle.

    \begin{verbatim}
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fontawesome}
    \begin{document}
    \faAutomobile\qquad\faBicycle
    \end{document}
    \end{verbatim}
    \faAutomobile\qquad\faBicycle

    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Alpine Linux, since the package [ttf-font-awesome](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.11/community/x86_64/ttf-font-awesome) only has Font Awesome 5, you need to manually download Font Awesome 4 from

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/v4.7.0/fonts/FontAwesome.otf

and place it in folder `/usr/share/fonts/X11/OTF`. You can replace the tag 4.7.0 with latest release in 4.x branch.

Alternatively, you can also install the [ttf-font-awesome-4](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/ttf-font-awesome-4) package from *testing* repository. (I have no idea why the package never made it to stable.)

Comment: ? This works for me, why downvote?