# Xetex - Font not found!

Tags: fonts, xetex, preamble

I'm a TeX Newbie and I'm trying to get XeTex to work with FontAwesome. Initially I got the error : The font "FontAwesome" cannot be found. So I added the path defaultfontfeatures as suggested in: [FontAwesome font not found?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132888/fontawesome-font-not-found)

```
      \usepackage{fontspec}
      \defaultfontfeatures{
       Path = /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmfdist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/ } 
      \usepackage{fontawesome,url}
```

Now I want to choose some other fonts like these:

```
       \setromanfont[Mapping={tex-text}, 
          Numbers={OldStyle},
          Ligatures={Common}]{Minion Pro}
       \setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,
          Ligatures={Common}, 
          Colour=AA0000]{Unit-Medium}
       \setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text,Scale=0.72]{Consolas} 

       \newfontface\scheader[SmallCapsFont={Minion Pro},SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Minion Pro}

       \newfontface\addressblock[Mapping={tex-text}, 
             Numbers={OldStyle},
             Ligatures={Common}]{Minion Pro Medium Caption}
```

I get the following error:

```
       kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `[/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/Minion Pro]/ICU', contains '['

       The font "Minion Pro" cannot be found.
```

What can I do to fix this?

### EDIT:

The error regarding fontawesome:

```
                )) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty
                kpathsea: Running mktextfm FontAwesome
                /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation F for FontAwesome.
                /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
                mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome
                This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013)


                kpathsea: Running mktexmf FontAwesome
                ! I can't find file `FontAwesome'.
                <*> ...our; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome

                Please type another input file name
                ! Emergency stop.
                <*> ...our; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome

                Transcript written on mfput.log.
                grep: FontAwesome.log: No such file or directory
                mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome' failed to make FontAwesome.tfm.
                kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.


                !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                !
                ! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
                ! 
                ! The font "FontAwesome" cannot be found.
                ! 
                ! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
                ! 
                ! For immediate help type H <return>.
                !...............................................  

                l.27 \newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}

                ?
```

Comment: What does MinionPro do in a Fontawesome directory? Usually MinionPro is in a subdirectory of where Adobe Reader is installed (at least that's the way it is under Windows). Also, `texmf- dist` shouldn't have a space.

Comment: My guess is that when I set the path to FontAwesome with \defaultfontfeatures then Tex automatically looks for all fonts in this directory? ... the dist space is because of the copy paste, will edit that.

Comment: Tex automatically looks in the relevant directories in `texmf-dist`. You don't have whatever to do, if your installation is correct. Btw you forgot  the hyphen in `texmf-dist`on setting the path. Also, you should update you installation. A lot of packages have changed (in particuler FontAwesome, which has many more icons now).

Comment: I updated the my distribution. The problem persists. FontAwesome is not located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've installed the font in a proper texmf directory, run `texhash` or the equivalent for your system. XeTeX will then find the font without having to specify the location.

Secondly, including `Path` in `\defaultfontfeatures` is almost certainly wrong in almost all cases. This is what is causing your error — after specifying a `Path`, fontspec assumes that the font to be loaded is specified by filename. So when you write

```
\setromanfont[Mapping={tex-text}, 
          Numbers={OldStyle},
          Ligatures={Common}]{Minion Pro}
```

this is equivalent to

```
\setromanfont[
          Path = /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmfdist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/ ,
          Mapping={tex-text}, 
          Numbers={OldStyle},
          Ligatures={Common}]{Minion Pro}
```

which in turn means that "Minion Pro" will be attempted to be loaded by filename from the `fontawesome` directory. This obviously fails!

---

Short answer: just delete the line including `\defaultfontfeatures` and you should be right, as long as `fontawesome` is installed correctly.

(By the way, `\setromanfont` has now been deprecated for many many years; you should use `\setmainfont` instead.)

Comment: I understand. How do I check that Fontawesome is installed correctly? I run texhash and this is the output: texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: Done

Comment: If you find that it does work to load the package with \defaultfontfeatures setting the path (does fontawesome use fontspec internally?) then just do that and then follow it up with \defaultfontfeatures{} to clear the setting.

Comment: You need to execute `sudo texhash`

Comment: I have done that. Still I get the same error, which I posted in an edit.

Comment: Also, the reason I set default path to fontawesome is because of the answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132888/fontawesome-font-not-found. I have added this in the question.

Comment: See my first comment above then.