# The font "FontAwesome" cannot be found

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, mactex, fontawesome

I am trying to compile `resume.tex` that uses `awesome-cv` class following  [this resume template](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/tree/master/examples). I get the following error:

```
usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/public/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty: 45: font spec error: "font-not-found"
The font "FontAwesome" cannot be found.
l.45 \newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
```

The problem arises on line 77 of `awesome-cv.cls` when running this line: `\RequirePackage{fontawesome}`. This problem has been mentioned in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132888/fontawesome-font-not-found). I tried the following lines of code in a `test.tex` file and was able to run it where these three options all worked: `LaTeX`, `XeTex` and `LuaLaTex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faTwitter
\end{document}
```

My confusion is that how come I can run the above lines of codes successfully, but `TeXShop` fails to require the same package when I run `resume.tex`. Adding a path (below) as suggested by one of the solutions from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132888/fontawesome-font-not-found) didn't work either.

```
\defaultfontfeatures{
Path = /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/ }
```

PS: I just downloaded and installed the newest distributions of mactex.

Thanks for your help

UPDATE:

Beside `resume.tex`, I have a class file named `awesome-cv.cls` and also `fontawesome.sty` and a `fonts` folder that contains files such as `FontAwesome.ttf`, `Roboto-Bold.ttf`, etc. If I run `resume.tex` in `latexshare` website using `LuaLaTex`, it works without any problem. By putting `fontawesome.sty` and fonts folder and referring to them in `awesome-cv.cls`, we make sure we are using the right file. Now, if I try that in my MacBook Pro, I get this error (yellowish message) where the problem happens at Line 12 of `fontawesome.sty` when it is called in `awesome-cv.clos`:

```
% Define shortcut to load the Font Awesome font.
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
```

***: If I erase `fontawesome.sty` and fonts folder, I get a very similar error this time stating the installed location of `fontawesome` package:

```
usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/public/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty: 45: font spec error: "font-not-found"
The font "FontAwesome" cannot be found.
l.45 \newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
```

[image]

Comment: If you compile with `xelatex` you can install `fontawesome` as a system font.

Comment: @Bernard Where do I install `fontawesome` as a system font if I run `TeXShop` using `xelatex`? I run it and it gives me the same error.

Comment: You install them like all others fonts for MacOS. I can't tell you more about it, as I don't  use a Mac myself. But perhaps the problem is in  `resume.tex` itself.

Comment: @Bernard The error happens when I try to load `fontawesome` package specifically in `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}` inside `fontawesome.sty`. I am not sure it's due to a problem in `resume.tex`

Comment: Why don't you simply load the `fontawesome` package  and use, viz. `\faTwitter`?

Comment: @Bernard I am trying to figure out why loading `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}` inside `fontawesome.sty` raises an error when being called from `awesome-cv` class, but works fine if I load the package in other conditions. I guess somehow the path is not detected in that case.

Comment: in a normal texlive fontawesome is not in a public folder `/tex/latex/public/fontawesome/`. Did you copy some local version there?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't make any manual changes to the fonds folders. I am wondering if `fontawesome` is not in a public folder, why does `\faTwitter` example works? If that is the case. should I emphasize a `PATH` using something like `\newfontfamily{\FA}[PATH]{FontAwesome}` inside `fontawesome.sty` or I need to make a public folder with the fonts?

Comment: If I run the document in [https://www.sharelatex.com/](https://www.sharelatex.com/) there is no problem and the codes runs successfully using `LuaLaTex`

Comment: I didn't mean the fonts but the sty. Run the failing example with lualatex and also the one that works and show the log-files.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just added an `UPDATE` section and covered the error. It is strange! It is working fine in `sharelatex`. Also, I can load `fontawesome` and use it for other tasks!

Comment: Sigh. When I write "log-files" I mean log-files and not "some snippet that you think is relevant". I need a complete log of a working and a failing compilation to be able to compare them.

Comment: Please provide the log from the working example on the MacBook to compare with the non-working case on the same system. Please post log files here or on a pastebin-type site rather than dropbox, which is a PITA. I accidentally downloaded the file, but removed it. Sorry, but I don't trust `.zip` files from unknown sources.

Comment: @cfr Sure. The log file containing the error is here [http://pastebin.com/ty15UGC0](http://pastebin.com/ty15UGC0) and the one working is [http://pastebin.com/WEHxBNPp](http://pastebin.com/WEHxBNPp), both run on MacBook Pro.

Comment: The successful run is with LuaTeX. What happens if you compile the minimal example document with XeTeX?

Comment: As @UlrikeFischer said, there is definitely something weird with your installation. That is not the correct path for `fontawesome.sty`.

Comment: Don't use the class file. If you like it, take the bits which are important and incorporate those. The class does several things it shouldn't. Moreover, it is not designed to be used out-of-the-box. You have to adapt it to your system in order to use it. It includes, for example, `\newfontfamily\FA[Path=\@fontdir]{FontAwesome}` which is not going to work well ... If you insist, try commenting out that line.

Comment: @cfr If I run the minimal example with `XeLaTeX`, I get an error similar to the error I get when running `resume.tex` which happens at l12 `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}`

Comment: @cfr When running the minimal example with `LuaLaTeX`, it works perfectly and the location of `fontawesome` is at `usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/FontAwe
some.otf`. Doesn't that tell us that the installation is fine?

Comment: Regarding the line `\newfontfamily\FA[Path=\@fontdir]{FontAwesome}`, I agree with you. I have a `fonts` folder beside `.tex` file. The same combination works fine in `sharelatex`. Currently I am running it there, but I am baffled why it does not work on my laptop.

Comment: The engines find fonts differently. That a font is installed correctly for use with one doesn't mean it will work with the other. Perhaps look at the `fontspec` manual to see what it says about the use of `Path` with XeTeX?