# How to typeset a loudspeaker icon?

Tags: symbols

I would like to include a [loudspeaker icon](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Speaker_Icon.svg), for instance by defining my own command `\myloudspeaker`:

[image]

I looked at [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/) and the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) provides a number of options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\faBullhorn \quad \verb|\faBullhorn| \\
\faVolumeOff \quad \verb|\faVolumeOff| \\
\faVolumeDown \quad \verb|\faVolumeDown| \\
\faVolumeUp \quad \verb|\faVolumeUp|

\end{document}
```

You're probably after `\faVolumeUp`.

Comment: See also [Fontawesome font not found](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132888/fontawesome-font-not-found).

Comment: There's a typo in volume down.

Comment: Bullhorn haha. That made me laugh given the question's context :)

Answer (score 20):

Here, I just string stuff together (e.g., `\rule`, `\blacktriangle`, and `)`)...  Works across different font sizes.  EDITED to provide different volume settings with the syntax `\loudspeaker[<volume>]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}
\newcommand\vcent[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}}
\newcommand\loudspeaker[1][3]{\ensuremath{\vcent{\rule{.6ex}{.6ex}}\kern-.5ex%
  \vcent{\scalebox{.6}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=center]{90}{$\blacktriangle$}}}%
  \ifnum#1>0\relax\kern.1ex\vcent{\scalebox{.3}{)}}\ifnum#1>1\relax\kern-.15ex%
  \vcent{\scalebox{.4}{)}}\ifnum#1>2\relax\kern-.23ex\vcent{\scalebox{.5}{)}}%
  \fi\fi\fi}%
}
\begin{document}
This is a loudspeaker: \loudspeaker.

This is volume 0: \loudspeaker[0].

This is volume 1: \loudspeaker[1].

This is a volume 2: \loudspeaker[2].

\LARGE LARGE loudspeaker: \loudspeaker.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a variant with the sound waves in tt font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}
\newcommand\vcent[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}}
\newcommand\loudspeaker[1][3]{\ensuremath{\vcent{\rule{.6ex}{.6ex}}\kern-.5ex%
  \vcent{\scalebox{.6}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=center]{90}{$\blacktriangle$}}}%
  \ifnum#1>0\relax\kern.05ex\vcent{\scalebox{.4}{\ttfamily)}}%
  \ifnum#1>1\relax\kern-.4ex\vcent{\scalebox{.56}{\ttfamily)}}%
  \ifnum#1>2\relax\kern-.55ex\vcent{\scalebox{.7}{\ttfamily)}}%
  \fi\fi\fi}%
}
\begin{document}
This is a loudspeaker: \loudspeaker.

This is volume 0: \loudspeaker[0].

This is volume 1: \loudspeaker[1].

This is a volume 2: \loudspeaker[2].

\LARGE LARGE: \loudspeaker.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare, for example, to https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Speaker_Icon.svg, cited by the OP.

Comment: I accepted Werner's answer because its an easier solution (for not yet very experienced LaTeX users), but I like your creative solution that I might consider in the future.

Answer (score 17):

is U+1F4E2 so if you have a font that shows this (eg if you can see the symbol at the start of this line in your browser) then you can use it directly from xetex or luatex, eg

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Segoe UI Emoji}
\begin{document}
---  ---
\end{document}
```