# issues with font awesome in Tex Live

Tags: fonts, fontawesome

I am using a fantastic [template](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) to try and generate a CV. I have installed Tex Live 2016 this morning.

When I try and compile the `cv.tex` document, I am prompted with the following error:

```
"fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font FontAwesome cannot be found...."
```

on Line 164. The document successfully compiles with the Educations, Skills, Experience sections but does not include the heading (persons name and contact details).

Following this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation), I tried to place the relevant .ttf files in my local directory, using

```
~texmf\tex\xelatex\fonts\truetype\awesomefont
```

But this has not helped.

A contributor to the github document informed me that the fontawesome package is installed with a default TeX Live installation. [As said here](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/issues/115). He then suggested I compile the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faCodeFork
\end{document}
```

For which I generate a blank document. **So where must I place the .sty or .ttf files so the document can be successfully compiled?**

Comment: Does latex actually know the font is there? Can it be found using `kpsewhich` also doesn't fontspec use the font cache to look for fonts? Thus that has to be updated.

Comment: [Crosslink]https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/issues/115)

Comment: Since fontawesome should already be in tl16, that extra stuff you've added might confuse latex. What does the mwe say if you rename that `~/texmf` folder? (to make xelatex ignore it).

Comment: the MWE ran and exited normally, but only generated a blank page

Comment: and I have since deleted awesomefont from ~texmf\

Comment: and a search of ´fontawesome´ within tex live 2016 directory shows it has  been installed

Comment: Have you refreshed your filename database? Or tried to place the ttfs in the same folder as the document?

Comment: the solution by macmadness86 provides a MWE to generate the twitter logo http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132888/fontawesome-font-not-found . Now I am just trying to include that into the cv.tex document. But I am not sure why the name (in large letters) is still not being generated

Comment: Did you try installing  `fontawesome` as a system font? xelatex can use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132888/fontawesome-font-not-found) by @macmadness86, the MWE above needs to be slightly edited, so that:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%\defaultfontfeatures{
%  Extension = .otf
%}
%\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newfontfamily\fatest{FontAwesome.otf} % Explicitly provide .otf
%or
%\newfontfamily\fatest[Extension=.otf]{FontAwesome}


\begin{document}
    %\faTwitter This is a test
    {\fatest\char"F099} This is a test
\end{document}
```

**And** more specifically within the `cv.tex`file, one must dive into the `awesome-cv.cls` file and change:

```
\newfontfamily\FA[Path=\@fontdir]{FontAwesome}
```

to

```
\newfontfamily\fatest{FontAwesome.otf}
```

and

```
\newfontfamily\headerfont[
  Path=\@fontdir,
```

to

```
\newfontfamily\headerfont[
  Path=/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/
```

Comment: Make sure not to cross any license stuff.