# Use Fontawesome Icons wiht Xelatex

Tags: xetex, fontawesome

I want to use the fontawesome icons in my document. After trying around a little i got to the following code:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\faTwitter

\end{document}
```

The code is compiling and no error is shown, sadly there is no "twitter-icon", but just a grey square displayed, so it looks like the icon would not be found. Did I forget to do something?

Comment: Possibly there is some more information in the `.log` file. Look for the line starting with 'Package: fontawesome' and below. If you can't find anything yoursefl, then you can add the contents of (that part of) the log file to your question.

Comment: Do you have the actual FontAwesome font installed? (It doesn't need to be installed with PDFLaTeX but is required for XeLaTeX.) If not, then this may be a duplicate of [FontAwesome font not found?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132888)

Comment: I'm not sure wether they are really installed. I used to try [this](https://coderwall.com/p/r67dyq/using-font-awesome-with-xe-latex) but that did not work out either. Can I conform if the right fontawesome is installed?

Comment: One way to check if the font is installed is to open a word processor (Microsoft Word, LibreOffice Writer, etc.) and see if the font is in the list.

Comment: If the font isn't installed (or if it's installed but isn't found) there should be an error message from `fontspec` in the `.log` file.