# Error compiling with fontawesome package

Tags: fontawesome, awesome-cv, fontawesome5

I'm trying to compile a motivation letter, for which I used the [awesome LaTex template](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV). I've just opened the .tex file and compiled it: no way, it doesn't compile, I get the following error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
./fontawesome.sty:12: fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "FontAwesome" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  
                                                  
l.12 \newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
```

Well, if you download the template you'll see it's full of files and so on, so I tried to simplify: I got that the problem was with these icons, so I went to [this basic page talking about this](https://latexdraw.com/fontawesome-ready-icons-to-use-in-latex/#:%7E:text=An%20icon%20is%20inserted%20by,current%20package%20with%20new%20icons.), and I copy-pasted the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{standalone}
 
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
 
\begin{document}
    This is an example of an open folder 
    with a \verb|regular| style: \faIcon[regular]{folder-open} 
\end{document}
```

and (always using XeLaTex) I got the same error.
I'm using a 2021 Mac, with latest version of TexShop and 2021 Tex Live.

Comment: Since you are on Mac, have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132893/119 ? The answer suggests that with XeLaTeX you need to make sure that the OS knows about the font, and this can be done by opening the font in FontBook and "installing" it. (I am assuming that the last sentence makes more sense to a Mac user than it does to me.)

Comment: @Joe The code you showed can't generate the same error message. (The message comes from the `fontawesome` package, not from `fontawesome5`) For `fontawesome` this is a known issue in XeLaTeX and you can follow Willie Wong's comment, but if the `fontawesome5` document doesn't work than there is something else wrong. I can't say more without seeing the actual error message.

Comment: @Joe, is this question still open, or is it resolved?

Comment: @MS-SPO: a colleague of mine solved. But I don't know how, so putting an answer would be great both for me and for other users having the same issue, I guess

Comment: @Joe Getting an answer first requires to know which error you got and especially which of the two packages you are actually asking about.

Comment: @Joe, Ok, but who can and should do it? Besides the info that was just requested from you, perhaps your colleague can note down his solution? Thanks