# Change MinionPro Math fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, minionpro

I have installed MinionPro.sty and like the text part of the font very much for my thesis. I do not like the numbers though since they disturb readability when there are many numbers in the text. So I tried

```
\usepackage[onlytext]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Minion Pro}
```

My platform is Windows, MikTeX 2.9 (x64). I have also installed "Minion Pro" in C:\Windows\Fonts. When I try compiling in XeLaTeX, I get the following errors:

```
Undefined control sequence. \setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Minion Pro}
Missing \begin{document}. \setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Minion Pro}
Undefined control sequence. \setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Minion Pro}
Undefined control sequence. \setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Minion Pro}
Package mathspec Error: `amsmath' must be loaded earlier than 'mathspec'. \RequirePackage{amsmath}
```

So I compromised and tried Arno Pro for text and MinionPro for math as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175899/using-minionpro-for-math-and-arnopro-for-text) in LuaLaTeX. Installed Arno Pro into Windows fonts.

```
\usepackage[minionint,mathlf,onlymath]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[UprightFont=ArnoPro-Regular,
BoldFont=ArnoPro-Bold,
ItalicFont=ArnoPro-Italic,
BoldItalicFont=ArnoPro-BoldItalic,
Numbers={Proportional}]{Arno Pro}
```

No luck. First two errors with LuaLaTeX are

```
Undefined control sequence. Numbers={Proportional}]{Arno Pro}
Missing \begin{document}. Numbers={Proportional}]{Arno Pro}
```

EDIT: Complete main.tex file below

```
\newif\iflayoutversion
% \layoutversiontrue
\layoutversionfalse

\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{sty/fncychapleo}
\usepackage[vcentering,dvips]{geometry}

\iflayoutversion
    \geometry{papersize={170mm,240mm},total={135mm,165mm}}
    % \usepackage[a4,cam,center]{crop}
    % \crop[font=\upshape\mdseries\small\textsf]
\else
    \geometry{papersize={210mm,297mm},total={165mm,235mm}}
\fi 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%% Now begin customising things. See the fancyhdr docs for more info.
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Chapter \thechapter. {#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps, .jpg, .jpeg, .png}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\graphicspath{{./fig/}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\usepackage[onlytext]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{mathspec}
%\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Greek)[Numbers={Proportional}]{Minion Pro}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{Minion Pro Italic}

%\usepackage[minionint,mathlf,onlymath]{MinionPro}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{MinionPro}[
%Extension = .otf,
%Path = ./fonts/,
%UprightFont = *-Regular,
%BoldFont = *-Bold,
%ItalicFont = *-It,
%BoldItalicFont = *-BoldIt,
%Numbers={Proportional}]

\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}

\algrenewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hskip3em// #1}

\include{title}

\begin{document}
\input{front-matter}

\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}

%\fancyhead[RO]{{\footnotesize\rightmark}\hspace{2em}\thepage}

\include{chap1/chap}

\graphicspath{{./fig/chap6/}}
\include{chap6/chap}

\begin{appendices}
\include{apndx1/chap}
\end{appendices}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\small
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,references} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please post a complete minimal document we can copy-paste-compile. Right now, it really isn't clear to me what you have or have not done. We also need to know how you installed Minion and Arno. Did you install these as any other font for you system? I don't understand what this has to do with `MinionPro.sty` since you don't seem to be using that at all.

Comment: The idea is if I can only change the way numbers (symbols are okay) are displayed through MinionPro.sty, my problem would be solved.

Comment: Do you really think `mathspec` can be used with LuaLaTeX? I don't think so.

Comment: No, I used XeLaTex for compilation with the above code (see the first set of errors above). Thanks.

Comment: @Erobrere What is the problem with the numbers from `MinionPro.sty`?  You can either use Old Style figures for text and/or math by using the options `textosf` and/or `mathosf` or you can have lining figures in text and/or math by using the options `textlf` and/or `mathlf`.

Comment: @Erobrere Does [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IGvgj.png) look okay?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have several options to use Minion Pro in LaTeX.

1. Use the `mathspec` package with XeLaTeX to load the OpenType text font as provided by Adobe Illustrator or Typekit.

   ```
   \usepackage{mathspec}
   \setmainfont{Minion Pro}
   \setmathsfont(Digits,Greek,Latin)[Numbers={Proportional}]{Minion Pro}
   \setmathrm{Minion Pro}
   ```

   > [image]
2. Use the `unicode-math` package with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (recommended) and load the OpenType text font as the text font and the commercial MinionMath as the math font.

   ```
   \usepackage{unicode-math}
   \setmainfont{Minion Pro}
   \setmathfont{MinionMath-Regular.otf}
   ```

   > [image]
3. Convert the OpenType fonts for use with pdfLaTeX following [these instructions](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/minionpro/README) and use the package.

   ```
   \usepackage[minionint,mathlf]{MinionPro}
   ```

   > [image]

For the sake of completeness here is the full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

%% XeLaTeX solution
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Greek,Latin)[Numbers={Proportional}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro}

%% Better XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX solution,
%% but requires commercial MinionMath
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
%\setmathfont{MinionMath-Regular.otf}

%% pdfLaTeX solution
%\usepackage[minionint,mathlf]{MinionPro}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\[ \int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2} \mathrm{d}x =
            \frac12\sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}}
            \mathrm{d}x\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha y^2}\mathrm{d}y =
            \frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It will be possible to extract the integral symbol of the `MinionPro` package when using the `minionint` option?

Comment: @juanuni Yes, that is possible. You need to copy some font definitions to your document to make it work. See [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Comment: Even when the `MinionPro` package is not installed?

Comment: @juanuni The package `MinionPro` is not necessary but you need the fonts. Follow the [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/minionpro/README) for how to install them.

Comment: Ok, I remember that README. Thanks.