# TeX Live 2014 - How to update otfinfo

Tags: fonts, texlive, updating

First, to give you an idea what I want to achieve: I would like to installing the Bembo Font Family via otfinst.py for pdflatex.

Why I don't use lualatex or xelatex is the missing support of some microtype features in both of them.

I have found this really good guide at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24699 which I went through, but otfinst.py gives me the following error:

```
python otfinst.py BemboStd*
Your otfinfo version is currently 2.100.
Please upgrade your otfinfo version to at least 2.38.
```

Where I'm stuck now is how to update otfinfo to a newer release > 2.38, to satisfy otfinst.py requirements.

Some information of my system:

```
uname -a
Linux ubuntu-server 3.13.0-46-generic #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 20:06:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

pdflatex -v
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)
kpathsea version 6.2.0
Copyright 2014 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.6.10; using libpng 1.6.10
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03

kpsewhich -expand-var='$TEXMFLOCAL'
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local

kpsewhich -expand-var='$TEXMFHOME'
/home/user/texmf

which otfinfo
/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/otfinfo

dpkg --get-selections | grep tex
luatex                      install
tex-common                  install
texlive-base                    install
texlive-binaries                install
texlive-font-utils              install
texlive-luatex
```

What is not clear to me is how to update otfinfo and in general in which latex or ubuntu package its distributed, though I think it does not come with texlive-font-utils looking at its content http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/all/texlive-font-utils/filelist.

Comment: http://www.lcdf.org/type/

Comment: Thank you for that hint. I had allready installed the latest version via `sudo apt-get install lcdf-typetools`. The problem is executing `otfinfo --version`,  which still points  `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/otfinfo`, prints 2.100 whereas `sudo otfinfo --version`, located at `/usr/bin/otfinfo` and installed by the ubuntu package, outputs the latest version number 2.92. It seems that the script is always refering to the otfinfo binary located under the TeX Live tree. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in `otfinst.py` which can't handle subversion numbers > 99 properly.
A quick and dirty fix would be to disable version checking by commenting out lines 269 to 271 in `otfinst.py`:

```
  # if float(m.group(1)) < 2.38:
  #   sys.stderr.write("Your otfinfo version is currently %s.\nPlease upgrade your otfinfo version to at least 2.38.\n" % m.group(1))
  #   sys.exit()
```

Comment: Yep, this seems to work perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have one question left: First the compilatoin was successful but after importing the font with `\usepackage{bembo}` I'm receiving a error message saying `! LaTeX Error: File 'nfssext.sty' not found`. It seems that you have experience with otfinst.py, do you have any idea on this one?

Comment: Maybe replacing `nfssext.sty` with `nfssext-cfr.sty` in `bembo.sty` could work. Or get ist from example.zip in the font installation guide: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide.  Better ask a new question.

Comment: @hetsch - I suggest you try `autoinst` from `fontools`.  It does a decent job creating necessary files and does not rely on `nfssext.sty`.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the long silence - I had no internet connection... @DG' - That did the trick! Thank you once again!

Comment: @Arash Esbati: Also, sorry for the long silence - I definetly have to try it out. Thanks!